# Splitting string using symbols in C

Tags: c, string

I have written a code trying to split a long string to get simpler strings so that i could sort them out... When i break from the nested loop, does it break up to the first loop entirely??

My input is "&$(,  My,na$me(is"

the output that i wanted is  "My na me is"
How can i solve this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char splitter[100];
    char mystring[1000];
    char newstring[1000][1000];
    int i,j,z,k=0;

    scanf("%s", splitter);
    scanf("%s", mystring);

    for (i=0; i<1000; i++){
        for (j=k; j<1000; j++){
            for (z=0; z<100; z++){
                if (mystring[j]==splitter[z]){
                    k++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    newstring[i][j]=mystring[j];
                }
            }
            if (mystring[j]==splitter[z])
                break;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%s ", newstring[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Note that this will fail in environments where the stack size is 1 MB or less (e.g. WIN32).

Comment: Why did you use two strings splitter and mystring.?

Comment: Try using goto keyword!!

Comment: @AadilAhmad because, the splitter one takes in inputs which can be up to a hundres of several symbols that are used to split the string which is mystring that could also hold up to 1000 characters

Comment: What I thought is that you wanted a string which contains only english alphabet and where there is another symbol in the string you replace it with space.Is that not correct?Also see my answer below according to my interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

First; C is not Python, you can't just use indent to denote blocks, you must use braces, i.e. `{` and `}`.

Second, no a `break` only breaks the closest-most loop its in, there's no way to `break` out of more than one level.

Third, you're looping over the strings as if they're always 100 characters long which they won't always be (for instance in your example they're not). This is wrong, you should use `strlen()` to figure out how long they are.

Fourth, you should check the return values of your `scanf()` calls, since it can fail.

Fifth, `newstring` is declared as an array of arrays, i.e. a gigantic one-megabyte 2D "square" of characters, which is clearly not how you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char splitter[100];
    char mystring[1000];
    char *tokens[500];
    char *token;
    int i=0;

    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", splitter);
    scanf("%999[^\n]", mystring);

    token = strtok(mystring, splitter);
    while(token){
        if(i)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%s", token);
        tokens[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, splitter);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are many mistakes in your code and I am unable to find out why are you doing those mistakes.For example I dint get why are you scaning two arrays and why are you using a two-D array.Another thing I would like to tell you is that scanf doesnt work when there is spaces in the string.According to your problem here is very simple solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
char splitter[100];
char mystring[1000];
char newstring[1000][1000];
int i,j,z,k=0;

gets(splitter);

for(i=0;i<strlen(splitter);++i){
      if(((splitter[i])>=65 &&(splitter[i]<=90)) || ((splitter[i]>=97)&&(splitter[i]    <=122)))
        mystring[k++]=splitter[i];
else
    mystring[k++]=' ';
 }
 printf("%s\n",mystring);
  //scanf("%s", mystring);


 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
int main()
{
   int i=0,j=0,t,f=0;
   char s[20];
   char b[20];
   printf("Enter the string\n");
   scanf("%s",&s);
   while(s[i] != '\0')
   {   
      t = s[i]; 
      if((t>=65 && t<=90) || (t>= 97 && t<=122))
      {
         b[j++] = s[i];
         f = 1;
      }
      else
      {
         if(f)
         b[j++] = ' ';
      }
      i++;
   }   
   b[j] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n",b);
   return 0;
}
```